# Android implements Runnable didn't Terminate

Tags: java, android, android-intent

i am making a client server connection using the [this Tutorial](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/incorporating-socket-programming-into-your-applications/) .
the problem i am facing that it doesn't stops, Log cat continue to show that client send data in an infinite loop. Also Server receives this data in an infinite loop

**here is my [code](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/incorporating-socket-programming-into-your-applications/)**

Any Suggestion/changes will be appreciated, I am stucked in this problem to yesterday coud'nt fined a good working solution from google.

thanks

EDIT

the client side code

```
    public class ClientThread implements Runnable {


    public void run() {
        try {

            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
            Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Connecting...");
            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 8080);
            connected = true;
            while (connected) {
                try {
                    Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Sending command.");
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new 
                     OutputStreamWriter(socket
                                .getOutputStream())), true);
                        // where you issue the commands

                        out.println(serverIpAddress);
                        //connected = false;
                        //socket.close();
                        Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Sent.");

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("ClientActivity", "S: Error", e);
                }


            }
            socket.close();
            Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Closed.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ClientActivity", "C: Error", e);
            connected = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Server Side

```
      public class ServerThread implements Runnable {
    private volatile boolean keepGoing = true;
    private volatile boolean firstLoop = true;

    public void requestStop() {
        keepGoing = false;
      }
    public void run() {
        try {
            if (SERVERIP != null) {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        serverStatus.setText("Listening on IP: " + SERVERIP);
                    }
                });
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
                while (keepGoing) {
                    // listen for incoming clients
                    Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            serverStatus.setText("Connected.");
                        }
                    });

                    try {
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new 
                       InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                        line = null;
                        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                            Log.d("ServerActivity", line);
                            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {

                                    serverStatus.setText(line);
                                    Log.d("IP recevied", line);
                                    requestStop();

                                }
                            });
                        }

                        break;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                serverStatus.setText("Oops. Connection interrupted.
                        Please reconnect your phones.");
                            }
                        });
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        serverStatus.setText("Couldn't detect internet connection.");
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    serverStatus.setText("Error");
                }
            });
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: You don't show any of your code. How are we supposed to help?

Comment: Edit your question and paste it in there, in a code block.

Comment: Please don't just link to the entire code. Post the relevant parts, or make a short, complete, runnable working example that highlights your problem.

Comment: Are you really expecting that guys will read this tutorial, try it step by step and *probably* get the same problem? Try to understand what does the code do, where the problem is and ask more specific question.

Comment: ok i have posted the problem area of code; sorry i am new here don't have much idea

Comment: @keppil and AlexR Sir kindly look at the code i have edited my Question

Answer (score 0):

to uncomment line `//connected = false;` should make it work .

after write stream operation you should exit from while instead of writing the same thing back .

Comment: that didn't make any difference

Comment: one possibility is that code jumping into catch block, where same connected = false will be needed . so check log Log.e("ClientActivity", "S: Error", e); if you will analyze your log more precisely then perhaps you will no need to try so many things :)